# How to show 2D image instead of 3D model when Image detected using unity 3D and vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am new to develop augmented reality apps. I have followed some tutorial to show 3D model using unity 3D and vuforia and it works fine. Now I need to show 2D image instead of 3D model

Comment: So, put an image as a texture onto a plane?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Bart in the comments. Go ahead and put in a plane. On the plane add a Texture that has the picture of the image you want to see.

> FYI: Augmented Reality is for the eyes to view a 3D image. Else we'd
>   just be using an app on screen.

Comment: Use the same technique with a movieTexture and you can be viewing a video on top of your tracker. (Vuforia has a sample for this).